# Java program to short and count

Tags: java

```
born | died
1902   1991
1941   1978
2004       
1957       
1989   2008
1909   2005
1918       
1913   2010
1979       
1961   2002
1977   2003
1909   1991
```

I need to write a method that takes the above information and returns every year in which the population was lower than the preceding year.

I'm beginner for java. Could someone help me how to achieve this please?

```
public class Lifespan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lifespan lifespan = new Lifespan();
        lifespan.computeLifeSpan();
    }

    public void computeLifeSpan() {

        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

      input.add("1902:1991");
      input.add("1941:1978");
      input.add("2004:");

      List<LifeSpanModel> filteredInput = new ArrayList<LifeSpanModel>();
        LifeSpanModel lifeSpanModel;
        int population = 0;
        for(String record:input) {
            lifeSpanModel= new LifeSpanModel();
            String earchRecord[] = record.split(":");
            lifeSpanModel.setBornYear(earchRecord[0]);
            lifeSpanModel.setDiedYear( earchRecord.length == 1 ? "Alive" : earchRecord[1]);
            filteredInput.add(lifeSpanModel);
            String k=map.get(lifeSpanModel.getBornYear());
            if(map.get(lifeSpanModel.getBornYear())!= null) { // add alive person here
                population = population + 1;
                map.put(lifeSpanModel.getBornYear(), lifeSpanModel.getDiedYear());
            }else {
                map.put(lifeSpanModel.getBornYear(), lifeSpanModel.getDiedYear());
            }

        }

    }

}
```

- If a member of the population was born in a given year, they count towards the
  population for that year.
- Likewise, if a member of the population died in a given year, they count towards the
  population for that year.
- Empty in died column means people still alive

For the example, a correct implementation will return the following years: 1992, 2003,
2006, 2009, 2011.

Comment: I’d probably use an `int` array with some 2020 entries to keep the difference in population compared to the previous year. So each time a person is born in year *y* I would add 1 to entry *y* of my array. And each time a person dies in year *y* subtract one from entry *y* + 1. At the end print the indices where the array holds a negative number.

Comment: If a person dies in 2010 (2010 is the most recent year with birth/death) and it means 2010's population is reduced by 1, then how would your correct answer has 2011 instead? If 2009 has `x` people, then 2010 would have `x-1`, and 2011 would still be `x-1`.

Comment: Personally, I would use a `Map<String, Integer>` representing year to population change. For every year in born column, increment the population of that year by 1, and for every year in die column, decrement the population of that year by 1. Lastly filter out all years with negative values.

Comment: You haven't stated what the issue with your code is so it's difficult to understand what you want help with. Unless all you want is for us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some issues in your correct implementation output.
Since someone died in 1978, 1991, 2002, 2003, 2005, 2008 and 2010 those years will have a lower population count than the year before them.

I have written a quick function that iterates every year from 1900 to 2019 and checks every person each iteration in a simple linear fashion. There are obvious optimizations that can be implemented (such as a Map or more clever searches) but this is a beginner question so I provided a basic straight-forward answer.

The output will be:
1978 1991 2002 2003 2005 2008 2010

```
private class Cont {
        Integer born;
        Integer died;

        public Cont(String input) throws Exception {
            String[] values = input.split(":");
            if (values.length == 2) {
                born = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
                died = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
            } else if (values.length == 1) {
                born = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
            } else {
                throw new Exception("bad input");
            }
        }
    }

public void doWork() {
    List<String> in = new ArrayList<>();
    in.add("1902:1991");
    in.add("1941:1978");
    in.add("2004:");
    in.add("1957:");
    in.add("1989:2008");
    in.add("1909:2005");
    in.add("1918:");
    in.add("1913:2010");
    in.add("1979:");
    in.add("1961:2002");
    in.add("1977:2003");
    in.add("1909:1991");
    List<Cont> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String inp : in) {
        try {
            entries.add(new Cont(inp));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    int bornCount = 0;
    int deathCount = 0;
    int aliveCount = bornCount - deathCount;
    for (int i = 1900; i < 2019; i++) {
        int prevAlive = aliveCount;
        for (Cont c : entries) {
            if (i == c.born) {
                bornCount++;
            } else if (c.died != null && i == c.died) {
                deathCount++;
            }
        }
        aliveCount = bornCount - deathCount;
        if (prevAlive > aliveCount) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every row is basically a person. You could create a class so that you could ask this person whether it is alive.

```
var person = new Person(1990, 2000);
person.wasAliveIn(1998);
```

Then it is simply a question of iterating over the years and counting how many people were alive at any given year.

Comment: can you explain little more please

Answer (score 2):

Because of the requirements said the "Likewise, if a member of the population died in a given year, they count towards the population for that year." which means if someone died the population of that year remain unchanged, and the death will count towards the next year( population - 1 for next year). I wrote a nodejs function, which output the exact sample answer, you can use it as a reference and write your own java function.

```
function checkPopulation() {
let data = [
    "1902,1991", "1941,1978", "2004,", "1957,", "1989,2008", "1909,2005", "1918,", "1913,2010", "1979,", "1961,2002", "1977,2003", "1909,1991"
]
let age = [];
for (let range of data) {
    let temp = range.split(",")
    if (temp.length == 2) {
        let person = {
            born: parseInt(temp[0]),
            died: parseInt(temp[1])
        }
        age.push(person)
    } else if (temp.length == 1) {
        let person = {
            born: parseInt(temp[0]),
            died: parentInt("0")
        }
        age.push(person)
    }
}
let aliveCount = 0
let preDied = 0
if (age.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 1900; i <= 2019, i++;) {
        let bornCount = 0
        let preceAlive = aliveCount
        if (preDied != 0) {
            aliveCount -= preDied;
            preDied = 0;
        }
        for (let count of age) {
            if (i == count.born) {
                bornCount++
            }
            else if (count.died != 0 && i == count.died) {
                preDied++
            }
        }

        aliveCount += bornCount;
        if (preceAlive > aliveCount) {
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to track the overall change in the population. This method is more efficient (time-complexity of `O(n)`).

```
public List<String> computeYearsWithReducedPopulation() {
    List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, Integer> populationDelta = new HashMap<>();

    input.add("1902:1991");
    input.add("1941:1978");
    input.add("2004:");
    input.add("1957:");
    input.add("1989:2008");
    input.add("1909:2005");
    input.add("1918:");
    input.add("1913:2010");
    input.add("1979:");
    input.add("1961:2002");
    input.add("1977:2003");
    input.add("1909:1991");

    for(String record:input) {
        String split[] = record.split(":");
        if (split.length == 0 || split.length > 2) continue;

        String born = split[0];

        // Born
        if(populationDelta.get(born) != null) {
            populationDelta.put(born, 0);
        }
        else {
            populationDelta.put(born, populationDelta.get(born).intValue() + 1);
        }

        if (split.length != 2) continue;
        String died = split[1];

        // Died
        if(populationDelta.get(died) != null) {
            populationDelta.put(died, 0);
        }
        else {
            populationDelta.put(died, populationDelta.get(died).intValue() - 1);
        }
    }

    return populationDelta.entrySet()
                          .stream()
                          .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().intValue() < 0)
                          .map(Entry::getKey)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is answered but an easy and simple way for juniors.

> The output will be: 1978 1991 2002 2003 2005 2008 2010

```
public void lifespans(){
        int[] born = {1902,1941,2004,1957,1989,1909,1918,1913,1979,1961,1977,1909};
        int[] died = {1991,1978,0,0,2008,2005,0,2010,0,2002,2003,1991};
        int min = Arrays.stream(born).min().getAsInt();
        int max = Arrays.stream(died).max().getAsInt();
        for(int i=min;i<=max;i++){
            int year = i;
            int birthYear = IntStream.of(born).filter(val->val<=year).toArray().length;
            int deathYear = IntStream.of(died).filter(val->val!=0&&val<=year).toArray().length;
            int birthYearLast = IntStream.of(born).filter(val->val<year).toArray().length;
            int deathYearLast = IntStream.of(died).filter(val->val!=0&&val<year).toArray().length;
            int populationYear = birthYear-deathYear;
            int populationYearLast = birthYearLast-deathYearLast;
            if(populationYear<populationYearLast){
                System.out.println(year+"|"+populationYear+"|"+populationYearLast);
            }
        }
```